# Add non Uefi Compability to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I have a usb stick with a full install of ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Unbuntu is running perfectly fine as long as I boot the Usb stick via my own machiene or a Virtual Box VM.

The Usb Stick has the purpose to be used in my school for my working there. Due to the bad configuration of the systems, working there is close to impossible.

I suspect that I can't boot the Usb at school Because they have uefi disabled. I'm not allowed to change that either. So I need my Usb stick to work with non Uefi Systems as well. **Is there a way to add non Uefi compability to Ubuntu?** Ideally afterwards.

Comment: School may disable booting from USB.

Answer (score 0):

Is your USB stick partitioning msdos or gpt?  msdos would be easy, there is room for a grub-install, gpt, you'd need to add a bios-grub type 1-2MB raw partition to hold parts of grub that cannot fit between the partitions. use grub-pc instead of grub-efi for the grub-install.

There is not much different for the actual install -- I've done the conversion msdos -> gpt, but never the reverse.

You might be better off using an install media with persistence.  You home machine is not likely to be identical to the school machine, and you might have driver problems.  Additionally, the install media might boot quicker than the full install.  You can leave a writeable partition to transfer files back and forth.